# Is there anyway to sync Outlook's calendar with Google's calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, outlook

Is there anyway to sync Outlook's calendar with Google's calendar? I've tried [following this](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89955) before but it doesn't work properly. I'm using Windows 7 and Outlook 2010.

The thing is, it's really easy to check my Google Calendar on my phone since I have an Android terminal, but on my computer I prefer just opening Outlook instead of opening a web browser and logging into Gmail.

Comment: Please tell us what's wrong and what does'nt work. Are you sure you've tried everything? Have a look at [this](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33322) and [this](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98563) or [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-sync-microsoft-outlook-with-google-calendar/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various third-party solutions that do this. Check out syncdroid.net for a unbiased review of them.  Or, my company also develops Outlook to Google sync software.  Does contacts, calendar, tasks.  You are welcome to try that.

http://www.companionlink.com/google/outlook/

Answer (score 0):

[Sync2](http://sync2.com/) might help you. I've used it to sync Outlook calendar folders with Google among office machines and would recommend it. Useful piece of software if you need such a solution.
You have ability to sync selected Microsoft Outlook Calendar with selected Google Calendar and vice versa. In addition to that you can sync Contacts and Tasks lists.

Comment: Why did you deleted your previous answer just to post it again?

Comment: Also, you and Matthew Smith are one and the same person?

Answer (score 0):

Google offers [Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync) to Google Apps for Work, Education or Government users. Users of consumer accounts should use a third party tool.

It's worth to say that Outlook allows to subscribe to public web calendars, but this is only for read access.

Comment: Doesn't work. After installation it said it's only for google apps business and not the free account.

Comment: I said that users of consumer accounts should use a third party tool. That means that it will "not work" for users with email addresses with gmail.com domain. It will "not work" either for users that have other domains but aren't  Google Apps accounts of the editions mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As for 2018, you could give [OGCS](https://phw198.github.io/OutlookGoogleCalendarSync/) a try. Have been using it for years and is pretty versatile.